What are the techniques to sharpening text in colored paper?
I need to sharpen this image:

Using online sharpening tool, this is the best I have:

It doesn't improve much, so I decide to do it manually. Following this tutorial, I use the Sharpen (Unsharp Mask) tool in GIMP and get this:

And following this manual sharpening tutorial I get this:

That's even worse. Is there any better approach to do? I notice that all tutorials use non-text images. Is it that text images are not applicable to sharpen?

Sharpening doesn't remove/mitigate the blurriness of text; it only enhances edges of the letters.
But here the problem of the image is that the text lacks contrast (so not that much "edge" for the sharpening tool), and it is somewhat deteriorated by the JPEG compression.
As a first shot:

Use the Brightness-Contrast tool to increase the contrast:



You can then try some sharpening



Another technique is to decompose the image using "wavelets", and then enhance edges by duplicating the decomposition layers corresponding to small details (Scale 1-3):


